# "git clone" throwing a "file already exists" error on .git/config?

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repo on a server I access via VPN (it's in the office and I'm working remotely) but get a "file exists" error on .git/config:

```
$ git clone //ip.0.0.0/path/to/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
error: could not lock config file ~/repo/.git/config: File exists
fatal: could not set 'core.symlinks' to 'false'
```

From some other questions (and prior experience), I know this usually means the file is being used by another process. What I don't understand is: how is that possible here? This file is being created by the clone operation, so I couldn't run another process on that file even if I wanted to.

Interestingly enough, however, if I instead use a remote desktop program to access my work computer (which has the server mapped as a network drive), the operation is successful (as long as I use the network drive name and not the IP address).

```
$ git clone N:/patho/to/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
done.
Updating files: 100% (80/80), done.
```

So, does anyone know what's going on here? I've been doing similar operations over IP for months now, so not sure what could have changed.

---

System description:

- I am connected to the server via a VPN, sending commands via Git Bash.
- The server is running Windows Home 10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363 (it's just a desktop tucked away in a corner).
- I'm using `git version 2.27.0.windows.1`

---

For a slightly more convoluted version of this story (should it be relevant), read on.

I've been having trouble with this origin repo all day, starting with `missing blob` or `failed to read delta-pack base object` errors when trying to push to it. Googling those errors made it seem the problem was likely some file corruption.

So I logged into the server, made a bare clone of my version of the repo (which I was earlier trying to push), erased the remote pointing to my version and then modified my repo to point to the new repo in the server (keeping the previous version safe just in case).

With this I got everything working and managed to make further pushes to the new repo.

However, when I then tried making a new clone of the repo, I got the error above.

---

Catalog of attempts:

- as suggested by [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072477/git-clone-throwing-a-file-already-exists-error-on-git-config#comment113303080_64072477), tried using `git clone --no-local` and `git clone file://ip.0.0.0/...` to avoid Git's local optimizations, but to no avail, same error.
- as asked by [@vgeorge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072477/git-clone-throwing-a-file-already-exists-error-on-git-config#comment113303493_64072477) throwing `\\ip.0.0.0\path\to\repo.git` on Chrome (on my home machine connected via VPN) opens the classic "Index of ..." page with the contents of the bare repo (hooks/, info/, objects/, refs/, etc).

Comment: what platform are you on, what git version are you using, (does this reproduce in a container, etc.)

Comment: @AnthonySottile edited. I also realized the problem vanishes if I use another computer which has the server mapped to a network drive.

Comment: When making a local clone (`git clone /path/to/repo` is always considered "local"), Git will try to use some shortcuts. It sounds like there's a bug in your Windows version of Git such that it doesn't *stop* using these shortcuts for this case where, apparently, they don't work here. That might be a known bug that whoever provides Git-for-Windows doesn't think is worth fixing, or maybe it's an unknown bug that depends on your specific setup.

Comment: Using `--no-local` disables the optimizations so you should be able to use `git clone --no-local //ip.0.0.0/path/to/repo.git` successfully, if the above theory is correct. (Another option is to use `file://ip.0.0.0/path/to/repo.git`.)

Comment: I think this is totally related to the network/file share configuration nothing to do with git, what is happening when you look this repo on the browser? is it possible to access via http ?

Comment: @torek: thanks, but I can unfortunately state that `--no-local` and `file://` had no effect. Curiously, the flag which throws the error (`could not set 'core.symlinks' to 'false'` in the case in the OP) changes each time: these last two attempts were `core.logallrefupdates` and `core.ignorecase`, for example.

Comment: @vgeorge: throwing `\\ip.0.0.0\path\to\repo.git` in Chrome opens the standard "Index of ..." page showing the contents of the repo (hooks/, info/, objects/, refs/, etc).

Comment: OK, well, so much for that theory. Best bets at this point include building Windows Git from source and debugging it directly...

Comment: If you can open it using browser then is it possible to clone via http ? Like http://ip.0.0.0/paty/.....

Comment: @vgeorge what do you mean? `git clone //ip.0.0.0/path/to/repo.git`? That's what I've been trying.